# How to perform Test automation on Web UI application designed using React and EMF parsley

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber-java, eclipse-emf

I have been assigned with a Web UI application designed using React and Eclipse EMF parsley.. I could find that there are no web element locators used except the div tags. I am looking for some better approach on how to perform test automation on this kind of application designs..

I have experience in Selenium, Java, Cucumber. Looking for suggestions further.

[image]